# Rails 4 and Devise: Having on field value (email) in the registration form, entered into both parent and nested model tables at sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-attributes

I am using devise. 
I have a member model (which is the model that devise uses)
A member has a 1 to 1 relationship with a user. 
I have a user model that contains all the profile information of the user.
The purpose of this is to keep the users info separate from devise.

I have a sign up form that has a nested form for user...therefore when the member signs up, on that same page they enter their info and that gets put in the user table.

The issue is simple enough.

I have one email field on the form (for member).

I want the value of email to also get entered into the database on save.

I tried

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

     has_one :user, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

    before_create :create_user

     def create_user
       user = User.new(:email => self.email)
       user.save
     end
  end
```

But what is actually happening with this is that 2 users get saved into the user table. One with the email field filled in and the rest blank, and a second with all the other attributes filled in but no email.

Here is my custom registration controller

```
    class Members::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController



     # GET /resource/sign_up
     def new
           build_resource({})
           resource.build_user
           respond_with self.resource
         end



     def configure_permitted_parameters
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
          u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_attributes => :first_name)
          }
          end

     private

     def sign_up_params
         params.require(:member).permit(:email, :password,  :password_confirmation, user_attributes: [:member_id, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :institution, :job_title, :about, :picture])
     end
```

end

The question is how can I get the email value into the member table AND the user table (along with the other data)

Here is the form. Don't like posting all this, but I guess it maybe required.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12">
<%= bootstrap_devise_error_messages! %>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4><%= t('.sign_up', :default => "Sign up") %></h4>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body">
    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: { role: "form" }) do |f| %>


        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :password %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>


        <%= f.fields_for(:user) do |user_fields| %>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= user_fields.label :first_name %><br>
              <%= user_fields.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= user_fields.label :last_name %><br>
              <%= user_fields.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= user_fields.label :job_title %><br>
              <%= user_fields.text_field :job_title, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= user_fields.label :institution %><br>
              <%= user_fields.text_field :institution, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= user_fields.label :about %><br>
              <%= user_fields.text_area :about, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>

            <span class="picture">
              <%= user_fields.label :picture, "Upload photo" %>
              <%= user_fields.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
            </span>

        <% end %>


      <%= f.submit t('.sign_up', :default => "Sign up"), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create_user
  user = User.new(:email => self.email)
  user.save
end
```

This is doing exactly what you are asking it to do, which is create a new User object.

The easiest way to accomplish what you want, is to update the associated User object once your Member object is saved. Like this

```
# member.rb
after_save :update_user

def update_user
  user.email = email
  user.save
end
```

Here, you are not creating a new User object, you are referencing the User object that is associated to the Member object via that `has_one` association you specified earlier.

Comment: Perfect. Easy solution. Hard to see the wood from the trees sometimes. Cheers Pal.